# Prolog custom operator to evaluate

Tags: prolog, logic

I expect the following code to print out [9 4], but this isn't working

```
:- op(20,xfx,i).

i(X,Y, Z) :-
         Z=[X,Y].

main:-
       RESULT is 9 i 4, write(RESULT).
```

Where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an operator is basically syntactic sugar; instead of writing `+(1,2)` we simply write `1+2`.
therefore, `9 i 4` is equivalent to `i(9,4)`

now, +/2 is not only an operator but also an [arithmetic function](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arithmetic_function/1)
note that the result should be a number so you cannot use it to return a list (and cannot use is/2 either)

Answer (score 2):

this works

```
:- op(800,xfx,i).

R is A i B :-
    i(A, B, R).

i(X,Y, Z) :-
    Z=[X,Y].

main:-
   RESULT is 9 i 4, write(RESULT).
```